# recursive grep and sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

file1:

```
   some line1
   some line2
   text1    text2   text3
   some line3
   text1    text2   text4
   some line3
```

I want to replace text1 with say NEW only in line which has text3

final output should be

```
   some line1
   some line2
   NEW      text2   text3
   some line3
   text1    text2   text4
   some line3
```

I am trying to do with grep and sed, but didnt help.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing recursive about what you are asking to do.

Comment: do you read any manual/doc/jelp/man about sed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed '/text3/s/text1/NEW/' file
   some line1
   some line2
   NEW    text2   text3
   some line3
   text1    text2   text4
   some line3

$ awk '/text3/{sub(/text1/,"NEW")}1' file
   some line1
   some line2
   NEW    text2   text3
   some line3
   text1    text2   text4
   some line3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '/text3/s/text1/NEW/g' file
some line1
some line2
NEW    text2   text3
some line3
text1    text2   text4
some line3
```